# Losing Audio while connect to Bluetooth SCO

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-audiomanager, nuance

I know this is a very specific issue, but I'm hoping someone else has some insight.

I am using a third Party TTS (Text to Speech) and ASR (Auto Speech Recognition) library from Cerence. I've noticed on Android 12, and some Android 11 devices, when I use them together is will shut down the Audio output.  I can still use the ASR for input, but no audio will be played.

I'm not seeing much in the logs for this, but when this happens, I need to disconnect the BT headset and reconnect it.

In minimal testing, Shortly after enabled Bluetooth SCO, the Audio is lost on Android 12.

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
// Need to set mode so we continue to get the Audio in the BT headset.
am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
am.startBluetoothSco();
```

A similar thing happens on Android 11, but while I can make it fail reliably, I don't know a precise way to make it happen.

I'm wondering if anyone has any insight on how to debug audio issues. Is there certain logs I can pull or look for? Is there someway I can troubleshoot audio issues? When this happens I can't play audio in any way, as an example YouTube no longer has audio in the headset.  So either the audio is being redirected somewhere else, or it has crashed.

I'm also wondering if there is another way to take control of the mic outside of Bluetooth SCO, or if there is a SCO setting I should be using that acts differently.

**UPDATE:**

In more testing I've realized that the AudioManager mode is being changed by something from MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION to NORMAL.  I have not figures out why yet, but if I keep forcing the mode to MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, my audio continues to be played.

Comment: im too facing this issue but did you fix it??

Comment: I created a bug and have gone back and forth on this. 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/209493718

The key is the 12.27.2021 comment from Google

Please confirm if you are actually using usage AudioAttributes.USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION for playback and audio source MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION for capture.
Using any other usage or audio source will not keep IN_COMMUNICATION mode active.

Make sure any Audio object has the Audio Attribute AudioAttributes.USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION